# fs.readFileSync Error

Tags: javascript, node.js, cloud9-ide, fs

I am trying to use the html-pdf node module to generate pdfs from html. I am currently running this using the cloud9 IDE.

My code is:

```
var fs = require("fs");
var pdf = require('html-pdf');
var html = fs.readFileSync('./test.html', {encoding: 'utf8'});
var options = { format: 'Letter' };

app.post('/pdf',function(req, res) {

   pdf.create(html, options).toFile('./businesscard.pdf', function(err, res) {
     if (err) return console.log(err);
       console.log(res); // { filename: '/app/businesscard.pdf' }
     });
});
```

**I get the following Error:**

```
[Error: Fontconfig warning: ignoring C.UTF-8: not a valid language tag]
```

Does anyone know how i can resolve this issue?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> This is due to a bug in `fontconfig`. You can see [here](https://github.com/giakki/uncss/issues/166)

Open your terminal and execute `locale -a` you will see list of `fonts`. Then select it like  `LC_ALL=C`

may it can help

Comment: Sorry to put a comment here again. But this issue has returned. I again tried it your way and for some reason it didn't work this time but it did work the first time and I haven't changed anything. Can you help me? I have raised another question on Stack overflow (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45346678/c-utf-8-is-not-a-valid-language-tag-cloud-9-error)